# apprequest with picture?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stream, image, facebook-apps, apprequests

I want to post an apprequest to the friends of a user with a request-specific image/picture. Unfortunately, the apprequests do not seem to support any picture/image/attachement mechanism, and the standard application icon is not sufficient.
Is there a solution for requests to add images, or do I have to use stream or feed instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not customize the image that appears in the apprequest - as you have stated it used the standard application image that was uploaded in the app's settings.
You can however choose a photo when using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) as well as other information such as the description, the name, the link and a caption as demonstrated below:

```
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};

FB.ui(obj);
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, that works to add an image. Unfortunately, I need the semantics of a request. The user has to specify which friends to invite, and since it´s a real-world invitation, it must not reach other users that the user does not want to invite.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this... If you have some extra limitations/specifications, please edit your original post to contain this information.